# Spring webflux: ServerResponse redirection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

This is my related code:

```java
@RestController
public class GicarController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Mono<ServerResponse> gicar(@RequestHeader("GICAR_ID") String gicarId) {
        return ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("/me")).build();
    }
}
```

Issue arises when I'm calling to `_/login` endpoint:

```
$ curl -i -X POST localhost:8080/login -H "GICAR_ID: tre"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer

curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

1. Why am I getting an 200 http code response?
2. On spring boot logging I'm getting this exception:

```
022-06-27 13:11:19.931 ERROR 79654 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [9750a9d8-1, L:/127.0.0.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:33150] Error finishing response. Closing connection



org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$WriterFunctionResponse]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$WriterFunctionResponse and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Why above exception is reaised?

Any ideas?

Comment: curl does not follow redirects per default, try using the `-L` option

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring documentation `ServerResponse`

> Represents a typed server-side HTTP response, as returned by a handler function or filter function.

and it supposed to be used in [Functional Endpoints](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux/webflux-fn.html)

```
@Configuration
public class GicarConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(POST("/login"), this::loginHandler);
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> loginHandler(ServerRequest request) {
        var gicarId = request.headers().firstHeader("GICAR_ID");
        return ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("/me")).build();
    }
}
```

If you still want to use [Annotated Controllers](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux/webflux-controller.html#webflux:webflux-controller:webflux-ann-methods.adoc#webflux-ann-responsebody), use `ResponseEntity` instead

```
@RestController
public class GicarController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> gicar() {
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)
                .header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "/me")
                .build()
        );
    }
}
```